# Text file writing

Tags: python, text-files

Output I'm getting: Noah 010 03 07

Output I want: Noah 10 03 07

I know my code is messy and much larger than it could be but I just want it to work
Fs 1 2 and 3 are definetly set as intergers(known from other code)

```
f = open("Class 1 A.txt","a")
    f.writelines("\n")
    f.writelines(name)
    if fs1 == 10:
        fs1 = str(fs1)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines(fs1)
        f.writelines(" ")      
    else:
        fs1 = str(fs1)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines("0")
        f.writelines(fs1)
        f.writelines(" ")
    if fs2 == 10:
        fs2 = str(fs2)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines(fs2)
        f.writelines(" ")
    else:
        fs2 = str(fs2)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines("0")
        f.writelines(fs2)
        f.writelines(" ")
    if fs3 == 10:
        fs3 = str(fs3)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines(fs3)
        f.writelines(" ")
    else:
        fs3 = str(fs3)
        f.writelines(" ")
        f.writelines("0")
        f.writelines(fs3)
        f.writelines(" ")
```

Comment: plz elaborate the question. give little more description.

Comment: You should post the rest of your code, because if the only way there can be a leading zero for the first number in your output is if fs1 is not an integer.

Comment: I've fixed it now  anyway

Comment: @NoahHourigan, where is fs1, fs2, fs3 coming from? Are you reading it from a file, user input or some other way(please describe)?